# Why are the work function values for photoelectric emission different for thermonic emission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

I have seen equations like Richardson's equation and Einstein's photoelectricity equation thrown around, but is there a good explanation for why the means of where the energy came from results in (marginal, but distinct) differences between the energy required for photoelectric vs thermionic emission? One example is caesium, which requires 1.81ev under thermionic emission vs 1.9ev for photoelectric emission.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? I don't think its expected that there would be a difference. However, with the same sample, the measured value may be different due to impurities. For example, surface contamination affects thermionic emission a lot more than photoelectric emission. [This](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1714489) source for example shows thermionic is larger.